# Share JSON Data in TabBarController to view controllers

Tags: json, swift, uitabbarcontroller, xib

I am using a tabbarcontroller to show 3 xib's. I would like to decode JSON data in the UITabBarController subclass, and then share the data with the view controllers (as I understand that is the preferred way to do this). I had already successfully accomplished this individually in each view controller, where the same JSON data was getting decoded separately 3 times, but I am now trying to make the process more efficient by only dealing with JSON once.

I am currently getting the following error

> "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffee7ab7d98)".

Below is the code I am currently using. I'm mostly only including the code for the first view controller, but it is the same for the others

Here is one of the view controllers. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

```
class FirstCollectionViewController: UIViewController {

   var tbvc = CustomTabBar()
   var statisticsData = [Model]()

   let firstCellIdentifier = "FirstCellIdentifier"

   @IBOutlet weak var FirstCollectionView: UICollectionView!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       FirstCollectionView.delegate = self
       FirstCollectionView.dataSource = self

       FirstCollectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "FirstCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil),forCellWithReuseIdentifier: firstCellIdentifier)
   }
}
```

Here is the subclasses UITabBarController

```
import UIKit

class CustomTabBar: UITabBarController {

let website = "https:......."

var statisticsData = [Model]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let firstTab = FirstCollectionViewController(nibName: "FirstCollectionViewController", bundle: nil)
    let secondTab = SecondCollectionViewController(nibName: "SecondCollectionViewController", bundle: nil)
    let thirdTab = ThirdCollectionViewController(nibName: "ThirdCollectionViewController", bundle: nil)

      viewControllers = [firstTab, secondTab, thirdTab]

    downloadJSON(website: website) {
           firstTab.statisticsData = self.statisticsData
           secondTab.statisticsData = self.statisticsData
           thirdTab.statisticsData = self.statisticsData

           firstTab.FirstCollectionView.reloadData()
           secondTab.SecondCollectionView.reloadData()
           thirdTab.ThirdCollectionView.reloadData()
    }

}

func downloadJSON(website:String, completed:@escaping ()->()){

        guard let qurl = URL(string: website) else { return }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: qurl) { (data, response, error) in
            if error == nil {
                do{

                    self.statisticsData = try JSONDecoder().decode([Model].self, from: data!)

                    DispatchQueue.main.async{
                        completed()
                    }
                } catch {
                    print("JSON Error")
                }}
            }.resume()
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the data is loaded, you should assign the data to the `viewControllers` that are added in the `tabBarController's` Child list as below,

```
downloadJSON(website: website) {
      firstTab.statisticsData = self.statisticsData
      secondTab.statisticsData = self.statisticsData
      thirdTab.statisticsData = self.statisticsData

      firstTab.FirstCollectionView.reloadData()
      secondTab.SecondCollectionView.reloadData()
      thirdTab.ThirdCollectionView.reloadData()
}
```

You can also remove the below lines from `viewDidLoad` of `FirstCollectionViewController`, `SecondCollectionViewController` and `ThirdCollectionViewController`

```
tbvc = tabBarController as! CustomTabBar
statisticsData = tbvc.statisticsData
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I've added that in to the code above, however the "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffeea4c48d8)" error persists?

Comment: what is the exact line of code where you are getting this error?

Comment: @greg42627 I updated the answer, you can check that also.

Comment: I've removed those two lines from viewDidLoad. The error is occurring at this line "var tbvc = CustomTabBar()"

Comment: Actually you should really not create a new instance of `CustomTabBar`. Remove that line also.

Comment: If you want a reference of the tabBarController in `FirstCollectionViewController`. Either you can get like this `let tabController = self.tabBarController as? CustomTabBar` OR you can declare variable inside `FirstCollectionViewController` as `var tbvc = CustomTabBar?` and set from `viewDidLoad` of `CustomTabBar` when you are creating child controllers. e.g, `firstTab.tbvc = self`, `secondTab.tbvc = self` etc..

Comment: It worked! Thank you. I was getting an error with the reloadData() lines of code. At secondTab.SecondCollectionView.reloadData() it was saying "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value", but once I deleted the second & third to only show firstTab.FirstCollectionView.reloadData(), it worked. Can you explain why? Is this OK?